# Looping through cells in another workbook to copy specific values

Tags: vba, excel

I've been fighting with this for a couple days now, and am at a loss on what else to try. My goal is to have a prompt for where a workbook is saved, this spreadsheet is obtained from an external source and name/location can vary. After opening the workbook, switch over to the second sheet and start searching for the values to copy to the workbook the macro is run out of.

The code I have works great if I set a breakpoint at the calculation for the last row, and at the For loop. Without those 2 breakpoints, it appears that none of the information in the workbook loads before running the rest of the code.

```
Public Sub Clm2Count()
Dim i, j, k, last As Long
Dim wkbSource, wkbCrnt As Workbook
Dim str As Variant
Dim strArray()
strArray() = Array("THIS", "IS", "MY", "ARRAY")
Set wkbCrnt = ThisWorkbook

k = 1

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End With

Sheets(2).Activate
Cells(5,1).Select 'Trying to activate a cell before calculating last, didn't work

last = wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells(wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 51 To last
    If InStr(1, wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value, "TEST") > 0 Then
        For Each str In strArray
            If InStr(1, wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Text, str, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If InStr(1, wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Text, "A", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 2).Text, "B", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    If str = "MY" Then 'Specific value from the array
                        wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 3).Copy
                        wkbCrnt.Sheets(1).Cells(k, 1).PasteSpecial
                        wkbCrnt.Sheets(1).Cells(k, 2).Value = "QC"
                        wkbCrnt.Sheets(1).Cells(k, 3).Value = i & ", " & str
                        k = k + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                ElseIf InStr(1, wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Text, "C", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 3).Copy
                    wkbCrnt.Sheets(1).Cells(k, 1).PasteSpecial
                    wkbCrnt.Sheets(1).Cells(k, 2).Value = "QC"
                    wkbCrnt.Sheets(1).Cells(k, 3).Value = i & ", " & str
                    k = k + 1
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next str
        wkbSource.Activate
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Any ideas on what I might be overlooking?

Edit:
Here are images of the beginning and end of column A, with the identifiers removed
[Beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3HwK.jpg)
[End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXyCK.jpg)

Comment: For starters, you should add workbook and worksheet references to all your ranges to ensure you are referencing correct cells.

Comment: I added wkbSource.Sheets(2). to all the Cells references that were just referencing the active sheet, but it is still giving me the same problem.

Comment: What value do you think last should be and what is it giving? If you have values in column A beyond 10000 it will return 1 (or wherever the data starts).

Comment: Also `sheets(2)` might not be the sheet you expect - it is just the second sheet in order. Try specifying sheet name or code name.

Comment: After the code completes it shows the worksheet that the data I'm trying to obtain, so I know it is activating the correct sheet. As I stated, if I set a breakpoint on the step for calculating "last" and the beginning of the For loop, I am able to verify that last calculates correctly. Only when I let the code run in full does it calculate last as 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Sheets(2).Activate` use `wkbSource.Sheets(2).Activate`. Same goes for cells and any other kind of ranges you are using.

It is especially crucial to be as explicit as possible which is the target workbook when you have a multiple workbook interaction.

To find last row use this line:

```
last = wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells(wkbSource.Sheets(2).Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

**Edit**: The issue was caused by a hidden sheet - it is better to use sheets name in this case.

Comment: Updated to that, still getting the same problem. last is calculating as 1 when it should be 804 on my test workbook, and the loop is being ignored

Comment: Check my edit and edit your post with updated code. If you are getting 1 then it means that there is nothing in the column you are targeting. Are you sure your data in in column A?

Comment: Updated code and post; it is still giving the same result. Column A has several values all the way down to row 804, the first value being in row 3

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of wkbSource.Sheets(2) - column A?

Comment: Screenshots have been added, row 804 is merged through column C but this hasn't been an issue when stepping through my code

Comment: Is there any hidden sheet in this workbook? Or very hidden?

Comment: Apparently there is. I didn't even think to look for that, there's one hidden sheet in the "2" position, and 2 more after what I thought was sheet 2. After updating to sheets(3), it works as expected.

Comment: Ok, I highly recommend to use a worksheet name instead of index. Please approve the answer if I helped you. Have a great day :) One more thing - merging cells might look good but it might be problematic if you wish to run scripts on these cells - it's really better not to merge cells.